# Wall clock time scheduling for message generation with dummy input topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a question about a pattern we are using right now for scheduling message generation based on a state store:
We are writing to a state store based on processing state in our “normal” processing streams, built with the DSL.  We hooked up a `transform()` with wall clock time scheduling to look at the state store every n seconds.
Depending on the state we `forward()` a new message down stream for processing (our way of doing delayed retries). The `transform()` needs an input stream that has a dummy topic as an input, that will never see data.

Could this be done without the dummy input topic?
How are other people doing this?

Additional info after Matthias' answer:
[image: Topo]

The `schedule()` is used as a data generator based on timed lookups of data in the state store. This is used for retries of a side effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to share some code for regular processing with side effect and processing based on the punctuation without side effect. Otherwise, you won't use `MyTransformer` for both cases?

Thus, I am wondering if you could do everything in a single `Transformer` instead of having three.

```java
MyTransformer<K,V,R> implement Transformer<K,V,R> {

    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
      context.schedule(..., new MyPunctuator());
    }

    public R transform(K key, V value) {
      // for every record from the source topic do everything
      doSharedStuff();
      doStuffWithSideEffect();
    }

    private doSharedStuff() {...}
    private doStuffWithSideEffect() {...}

    private class MyPunctuator implements Punctuator {
        public void punctuate(long timestamp) {
          for(KeyValue kv : ...) { // whatever k/v-pair to want to "forward"
            // for every record you want to emit delayed, do only some part
            doSharedStuff();
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I replace my answer with a new one :) Hope this makes sense. Not sure what you exactly to in `MyTransformer`.

Comment: good input. we're gonna look at that. This would replace the need for the dummy input topic, when we do the schedule in the main stream...